# How to overload operator= using const char* and/or string?

Tags: c++, string, char, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have searched these kind of questions, but I don't still understand why my code has error and how to implement it...

What I want to do is create a class, which can be assigned by string and char* just like std::string...http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/

- string (1)   string& operator= (const string& str);
- c-string (2) string& operator= (const char* s);

I can write

```
string str1 = "haha"; //way(2)
string str2 = str1; //way(1)
```

So, I write this class...

```
class LinkedList
{
private:
    ListNode *first;
public:
    LinkedList():first(nullptr) {};
    LinkedList(const string &str);
    LinkedList& operator=(const string &str);
    LinkedList& operator=(const char *s);
    void Print_LinkedList();
    void Push_back(char c);
//    void Insert();
//    void Delete();
//    void Invert();
//    void Clear();
};
```

And, the method part is...

```
LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const string &str)
{
    if (str.length()%3 != 1)//legal string_input.length is 3n+1
    {
        cout << "LinkedList building error" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=3)
        {
            this->Push_back(str.at(i));
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const char *s)
{
//    if (???) //please give me some suggestions...
//    {
//        cout << "LinkedList building error" << endl;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        for (???) //please give me some suggestions...
//        {
//            this->Push_back(???); //please give me some suggestions...
//        }
//    }
    this->Push_back('x');
    return *this;
}
```

And, the main part is...

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList linkedlist1;
    linkedlist1.Push_back('x');
    linkedlist1.Push_back('a');
    linkedlist1.Print_LinkedList();

    string str_test = "H->a";
    LinkedList linkedlist2(str_test);
    linkedlist2.Print_LinkedList();

    string str_test2 = "H->A->h->o";
    LinkedList linkedlist3 = str_test2;
    linkedlist3.Print_LinkedList();

    LinkedList linkedlist4 = "x"; //there's an error in this line
    linkedlist4.Print_LinkedList();

    return 0;
}
```

Then, the compiler says,

```
"error: conversion from 'const char [2]' to non-scalar type 'LinkedList' requested|"
```

Could you tell me...

> 1.why dose my code have the compiler error?
>   2.how can I fix the bug?
>   3.some suggestions for implementing in the "LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const char *s){//how should I write here}"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're not calling the assignment operator, that's an initializer.

Comment: Oh! I got it! I have fixed the problem...thx a lot...